# Syntax Error : Unexpected Token Catch While Compiling EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a project in Node.JS Express.
I had several pages all of which are running fine but only one page (till now) is giving error in loading up.
When I ran that page a error pops up, that is :

```html
SyntaxError: Unexpected token catch in E:\nodeapp\views\adm.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass async: true as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12)
    at Object.compile (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:392:16)
    at handleCache (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Submit\Fresh\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
```

My adm.ejs file is :

```html
<%- include('../views/header') %>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="table_view_btn"> Voters / Candidates</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" onclick="javascript:window.location = '/admin/logout';"> Logout</button>

                <hr>
                <div id="voter_table">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                        <h4>Voters</h4>
                        <small>Click on the row item to verify the identity of Voter.</small>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Aadhaar</th>
                                <th scope="col">Constituency</th>
                                <th scope="col">Voted?</th>
                                <th scope="col">Verified?</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!--<% for(var i=0 ; i < voters.length; i++) { %> -->
                                <tr onclick="window.location='/admin/verifyvoter/';" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        1
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        Janit
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        ABC123
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        COR
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        True
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        True
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="candidate_table" style="display:none;">
                        <!-- <div>
                            <h3>Add Candidate</h3>
                            <form method="post" action="/addcandidate" class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cand_name" name="cand_name" placeholder="Enter Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="custom-select form-control" id="cand_constituency" name="cand_constituency">
                                        <option selected>Constituency</option>
                                        <option value="Jabalpur">Jabalpur</option>
                                        <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Add Candidate</button>
                                </div>
    
                            </form>
    
                        </div>
                        <hr> -->
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                        <h4>Candidates</h4>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Constituency</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!--<% for(var i=0 ; i < candidates.length; i++) { %>-->
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        2
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        Souvik
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Jabalpur
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I tried searching on the internet regarding this error but everyone showed that there is a problem in the include syntax which is correct for me.
Also my router file for this page has nothing else other than a get request which renders this page to the client.

Where's the problem then ?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the JS loop with its `{` in a JS comment, not a HTML comment

Comment: Which loop ? @Bergi

Comment: The `for(var i=0 ; i < voters.length; i++) {` and the `for(var i=0 ; i < candidates.length; i++) {`. Both of them have an unmatched open brace.

Answer (score 4):

<% for(var i=0 ; i < candidates.length; i++) { %>
seems your '{' wasn't closed with '}' and should be '<%}%>'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the for, }. it looks like <% } %>

Comment: This looks like a commenti